# issue with 'IdentityFile' in ssh config file

Tags: git, macos, ssh, gitlab

I encounter issue when I try to clone a project from gitlab. I have this error message:

```
clonage dans 'demossh'...
git@gitlab.myserver.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Impossible de lire le dépôt distant.

Veuillez vérifier que vous avez les droits d'accès
et que le dépôt existe.
```

I use this command line for cloning: `git clone git@gitlab.myserver.com:demossh.git`

But if I use this command instead, everything work fine:
`GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/privateKey" git clone git@gitlab.myserver.com:demossh.git`

here my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
host *
  # UseRoaming no
  IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain,AddKeysToAgent
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/controlmasters/%C
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPersist 600
  Preferredauthentications publickey
  AddressFamily inet
  Protocol 2
  Compression yes
  IdentitiesOnly yes


Host gitlab
  HostName gitlab.myserver.com
  User git
  port 443
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/privateKey
```

I use the same config with the same public/private keys in another computer, its work perfectly.

Someone can help me to fix this issue ? I dont understand how to find out whats wrong.

Just for recall, its a selfhosted gitlab server.

**EDIT1:** for reply to @torek answer

`ssh -Tvv git@gitlab.myserver.com` give me this output:

```
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/unouss/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/unouss/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/unouss/.ssh/config line 32: Applying options for ulille
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/Users/unouss/.ssh/controlmasters/f2a4e6b6312f02723d17bf22edff8059aeacd42d" does not exist
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.myserver.com port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/unouss/.ssh/privateKey type 3
debug1: identity file /Users/unouss/.ssh/privateKey-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

and `ssh -Tvv -i ~/.ssh/privateKey git@gitlab.myserver.com` this output:

```
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/unouss/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/unouss/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/unouss/.ssh/config line 32: Applying options for ulille
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/Users/unouss/.ssh/controlmasters/f2a4e6b6312f02723d17bf22edff8059aeacd42d" does not exist
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.myserver.com port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/unouss/.ssh/privateKey type 3
debug1: identity file /Users/unouss/.ssh/privateKey-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/unouss/.ssh/privateKey type 3
debug1: identity file /Users/unouss/.ssh/privateKey-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

and here the diff :

```
13a14,15
> debug1: identity file /Users/unouss/.ssh/privateKey type 3
> debug1: identity file /Users/unouss/.ssh/privateKey-cert type -1
```

PS: sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Eliminate Git while testing: run `ssh -Tvv git@gitlab.myserver.com` vs `ssh -Tvv -i ~/.ssh/privateKey git@gitlab.myserver.com` and see what's different in the debug outputs.

Comment: They'll be way too verbose to fit into comments. Just compare them to see what's *different* - why one works and one doesn't - and work from there to what's wrong with the one that doesn't work.

Comment: I edit my first post and add some output related to your answer

Comment: Note that my comments are not an *answer*, they're just instructions for getting more debug info. The curious thing is that it looks like *neither* ssh command worked (although that may be just my lack of knowledge about gitlab). Also, your `Host gitlab` won't apply to `ssh git@gitlab.myserver.com` but rather only to `ssh git@gitlab`, and *something* it does seem to be applied as the difference between the two is that `/Users/unouss/.ssh/privateKey` (an ECDSA key) is loaded twice, as one would expect from the `-i` argument.

Comment: We also see `debug1: /Users/unouss/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for *` and `debug1: /Users/unouss/.ssh/config line 32: Applying options for ulille` which means that your lines 2 and 32 are being applied, along with two comments about `/etc/ssh` applying options for all hosts at lines 20 and 102. So those are interesting places to look, but the real question is whether the two ssh's are working. If so, that means that the problem is that the ssh that Git launches by default (without setting `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`) is not your normal ssh.

Comment: *If that's the case* (hard to tell without one more debug which is run `GIT_TRACE=1 git clone ...` to see what ssh Git runs by default), then the fix is just to set `core.sshCommand` to `ssh` in your global Git config: tell your Git to use your systems's ssh, not some other ssh it's configured to use by default.

Answer (score 2):

You are connecting to "gitlab.myserver.com", but defined "gitlab" entry in `~/.ssh/config`. It was not picked up. This is the reason why your connection succeeds when you specify the path to the private key as an argument.

The section name must match the name you are connecting to. If you need both names, you can use a list:

```
- Host gitlab
+ Host gitlab gitlab.myserver.com
    HostName gitlab.myserver.com
    User git
    port 443
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/privateKey
```

And are you sure about port 443? Is gitlab ssh port set up to 443 from gitlab side?

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` uses the first parameter it finds. The more specific configurations should be at the top. I might be mistaken, but I think you should start with `Host gitlab` first.

The following is taken straight from the [`ssh_config` manual](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config):

> For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used. The configuration files contain sections separated by Host specifications, and that section is only applied for hosts that match one of the patterns given in the specification. The matched host name is usually the one given on the command line.
>
> Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning of the file, and general defaults at the end.